# SQL Fiddle: How do I insert into a single table from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sqlfiddle

I'm trying to write a MySQL script in SQL Fiddle.  I've got a 'Donut' table, a 'DonutOrder' table and a 'LineItem' table.  I want to insert into the LineItem table the DonutOrderID from DonutOrder (based on a SELECT) and the DonutID from the Donut table (based on a SELECT).  Obviously there are no common fields, so there is no way to do a join on them.

In MS SQL, I would just declare a couple of variable and store the 2 ID values to use in the INSERT statement, but SQL Fiddle won't let me create variables like that.

Does anyone now how I can grab these 2 disparate values during a single INSERT statement?

Thanks!

Comment: if these table don't have a common id how would you know which donutOrderID belongs to which donutID

Comment: Please add the table create staments and some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO LineItem (field1, field2) VALUES 
((SELECT DonutOrderID FROM DonutOrder WHERE param = ?), (SELECT DonutID FROM Donut WHERE param = ?))
```